# Do Get request with a complex type parameter in the request body with web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, integration-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I want to do an integration test for the below action.

How can I pass my requestDto object in the integration test?

Neither the GetAsync nor SendAsync method has an overload parameter to pass a custom object to the server.

```
[Route("{startDate:datetime}")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(DateTime startDate, [FromBody]LessonplannerGetRequest request)
{
    request.StartDate = startDate;
    var lessonplannerResponse = _service.GetPeriodsByWeekStartDate(request);
    return Request.CreateResponse<LessonplannerResponse>(HttpStatusCode.OK, lessonplannerResponse);
}

[Test]
public void Get_Lessons_By_Date()
{
    // Arrange
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _server.BaseAddress + "/api/lessonplanner/2014-01-14");

    var myRequestDto = new LessonplannerGetRequest();

    // Act => QUESTION: HOW do I pass the myRequestDto ???
    var response = _client.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken()).Result;

    // Assert
    Assert.That(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As Darrel Miller said:"Technically HTTP says you can send a body, it just says the body doesn't mean anything and cannot be used. HttpClient won't let you send one."

I post here my integration test with HttpClient doing a Get request with complex type + FromBody:

```
// Arrange
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _server.BaseAddress + "/api/lessonplanner/2014-01-14");
var myRequestDto = new LessonplannerGetRequest{ FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, SchoolyearId = 1, StartDate = DateTime.Today};
request.Content = new ObjectContent<LessonplannerGetRequest>(myRequestDto, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 

// Act
var response = _client.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken()).Result;

// Assert
Assert.That(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Of course is this is not the Http way some might consider doing it differentlly sending complex type via FromUri/query string.

Comment: If you are making an http request, you should serialize your requestDto object and send it via request.body.

Comment: HTTP semantics do not allow body for GETs. The more HTTP-ish way of doing this will be to pass in the request data in the URI and query string and bind to the complex type using `[FromUri]`. Just a thought.

Comment: @Badri Technically HTTP says you can send a body, it just says the body doesn't mean anything and cannot be used.  HttpClient won't let you send one.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Not true what you say I have just used the HttpClient in my integration test with GET + Complex Type + FromBody and it worked fine.

Comment: @Elisa  I get the error "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Comment: @DarrelMiller With my Code? Then I do not know for me it works. Really I debugged into the action.

Comment: @Elisa Using StringContent, yes.  With ObjectContent my test runner was hanging.  Not sure why, didn't have time to sort it out.

Comment: @DarrelMiller For sure Darrel With ObjectContent as posted above I works for me! When you repeat the test runner do you sometimes get an Exception to paste here?

Comment: @Elisa I just tried it again in a console app.  With ObjectContent the SendAsync just never executes the continuation.  It is really weird.  Anyway, this is all somewhat moot as you should not be sending a body with GET whether the client lets you or not.

Comment: Yes to be REST conform I just do it via FromUri now. You better edit your answer to: "YOU can pass a GET body but its not Http/Rest conform" :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT pass a GET body with HTTPClient.

Comment: @Elisa Sorry, I misread you question.  You want to send a body with a GET.  You can't do that.  HTTP says that bodies in GET messages have no meaning.

Comment: I have just sent my complex type via request body + Http Get and it works fine. Why does the web API allow it when Http spec forbide this?

Comment: The HTTP specs does not forbids it, but the HTML specs does. Since most clients and browsers supports both the HTML and HTTP specs, like HttpClient, they are often strict on the HTML part. WebAPI implements ONLY the HTTP specs (while MVC implements both, but might not be totally strict, not sure). See my answer below with the link to the HTML specs.

Answer (score 6):

HTML specifications says you cannot send a GET with a body.

HTTP specs allows it.

WebAPI allows it, because it is a service/REST and implements HTTP but not HTML, but many clients and browser won't allow it because they implement both specs and try to be strict.

As for the specifications ([RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 46; [HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) section 17.13.3) itself, it states:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content type.

(e.g. if you do a `<form>` with GET, it will parse all the form params and set them in the query string ?a=b).

In term of pure HTTP and in the context of REST services, nothing prevents that behavior, but not all clients will be able to handle it. It's mostly a best-practice advise when it comes to REST/WebAPI to not handle body data from HttpGet, only URI data (the opposite, POST /action?filter=all is usually tolerated for metadata/action qualifiers, but that's another discussion).

So yeah, it's at your own risk, even if used only internally. As not all clients handle it (e.g. HttpRequestMessage), so you might run into trouble like you have.